# Java: Deserializing Objects from Database Table Throws StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, database, serialization, deserialization, rowmapper

I'm working on deserializing objects stored in a database table. When attempting to read the serialized data using ObjectInputStream, I encounter a StreamCorruptedException with the message 'invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF'. The data is stored in a column named 'SERIALIZATION' in the 'OAUTH_CLIENTS' table. How can I properly deserialize the data retrieved from the database?

Here is my ClassicClientsService:

```
@Component
public class ClassicClientsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    private final JdbcTemplate dataTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ClassicClientsService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws OAuth2Exception {

        try {
            ClientDetails details = dataTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT SERIALIZATION FROM OAUTH_CLIENTS WHERE CLIENTID = ?", new ClientDetailsMapper(), new Object[]{clientId});
            return details;
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ers) {
            throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("Client " + clientId + " was not found", 1);
        }

    }

    private class ClientDetailsMapper implements RowMapper<ClientDetails> {

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public ClientDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
            byte[] temp = rs.getBytes("SERIALIZATION");
            
            return (ClientDetails) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(temp)).readObject();
        }

    }}

public boolean addClient(ClientDetails details) throws DataAccessException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(outBytes);
            outObject.writeObject(details);
            outObject.flush();
            outObject.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] szDetails = outBytes.toByteArray();
        dataTemplate.update("INSERT INTO OAUTH_CLIENTS (CLIENTID, PROTOCOL, SERIALIZATION) VALUES(?,1,?)", new Object[]{details.getClientId(), szDetails});
        return false;
    }
```

When i call the method "loadClientByCLientId" i am getting my Exception

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        migrateClients(args[0]);
    }

    private static void migrateClients(String clientId) {
        if (clientId.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("client id should be set as program argument");
        }
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        ClassicClientsService clientDetailsService = context.getBean(ClassicClientsService.class);
        OauthClientsManager oauthClientsManager = context.getBean(OauthClientsManager.class);
        clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
```

Logs:

```
    NFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:935)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:374)
```

Comment: Is the file a text file? Is the image that you're showing an image of the text in the file? If so, then you cannot use an ObjectInputStream to extract data from the file. In fact, you can only use ObjectInputStream if the file was written using an ObjectOutputStream. Your question appears to be missing this key information. In other words, a file must contain properly serialized data if you are going to be able to unserialize it.

Comment: `EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 05` looks exactly like the sequence of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686702/2711488)…

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It`s a column in database mysql. I have column 'SERIALIZATION' with serialized objects but i want to deserialize them and get data.

Comment: But again, how is the data saved to the database? Is it serialized with ObjectOutputStream? If not, then your attempt to use ObjectInputStream is doomed. Regardless, you will want to show your code that is used when storing the data.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, forgot about 'addClient' method. If we use this method we will have serialized object with header AC ED 00 05. But if you can see i have other header because i used old databaseDump with patch which stored this data for me. Holger gave a link where answer was that git changes headers. But nobody answers how to read this header. Updated code and question.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem with [this code](https://pastebin.com/qjhccVDw). Consider trying to isolate the code that is causing the problem and posting that.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to store that serialized data into a character-based column type?

Comment: Try removing BOM If the data contains a BOM, you need to remove it before deserialization. You can modify your mapRow method to strip these bytes if they are present in there.

Comment: or I think as an additional method you can use it:  `public static byte[] removeUtf8Bom(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes.length >= 3 && bytes[0] == (byte)0xEF && bytes[1] == (byte)0xBB && bytes[2] == (byte)0xBF) {
        // BOM found, remove it
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 3, bytes.length);
    } else {
        // BOM not found, return original array
        return bytes;
    }
}`. or may try to check a better way to do this.  hope it can direct you to a solution

Comment: It *shouldn't* have a BOM. If it does, then *something* is treating serialized data as text, which it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I created a new application(which does not make much sense) within a completely new project, and the data was successfully deserialized in this new environment.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, I had the same problem and found it was caused for the charset and collation of the tables, I set this on the persistence.xml options and it's solved, in my case it was using utf8mb4.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. The error emerges from an attempt to read Java serialization data. That's nothing to do with the character encoding of your db. Note my last comment before this one. You shouldn't be trying to serialize to a char column type if that's what's happening. You need a 'binary' type